# NHibernate, working with columns via reflection

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Scenario:

I have a JavaScript library that handles paging/sorting/searching of tables, with server-side hooks. I've wired up the server-side JSON calls, created a model binder that translates the passed-in values into a usable request object, and am now attempting to implementing searching.

Via the request object, I have access to a list of columns upon which to sort. I'm trying to write a generic function that will allow any table to pass in its columns, and generate .Where calls for each column and the search value.

The approach at the moment is to take the string property name, use reflection to get the actual value, then compare that to the search parameter. The *very* rough approach I'm trying is:

```
public static IQueryable GetSearchClause(IQueryable<object> query, DataTablesPageRequest pageRequest)
{
    var columns = pageRequest.ColumnNames.Split(',');

    for (var i = 0; i < pageRequest.Searchable.Count; ++i)
    {
        if (pageRequest.Searchable[i])
        {
            var column = columns[i];

            var test = query.Where(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(column)
                .GetValue(query.Select(z => z.GetType()), null)
                .Equals("test"));
        }
    }

    return query;
}
```

When I take a look at the resultant 'test' object, I get a very unpleasant stacktrace:

```
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitMethodCallExpression(MethodCallExpression expression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.Visit(Expression expression, VisitorParameters parameters)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.VisitWhereClause(WhereClause whereClause, QueryModel queryModel, Int32 index)
   at Remotion.Linq.Clauses.WhereClause.Accept(IQueryModelVisitor visitor, QueryModel queryModel, Int32 index)
   at Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitBodyClauses(ObservableCollection`1 bodyClauses, QueryModel queryModel)
   at Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.Visit()
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.GenerateHqlQuery(QueryModel queryModel, VisitorParameters parameters, Boolean root)
   at NHibernate.Linq.NhLinqExpression.Translate(ISessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(String queryIdentifier, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan.CreateTranslators(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan..ctor(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan..ctor(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.PrepareQuery(Expression expression, IQuery& query, NhLinqExpression& nhQuery)
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()
```

Can I even accomplish what I'm trying to with this technique, or should I really be using a per-entity approach, since I would know ahead of time which columns to search by (and skip the whole reflection bit)?

Comment: Can you use ICriteria? Then you wouldn't need any reflection, just use the property name.

Comment: Haven't used ICriteria yet - but it looks much easier at a glance. I'll monkey about with it a bit. Since you asked whether I can use it...is there some reason I would not want to use it? I'm still a bit confused at the amount of ways you can write queries in NH; is one preferred over another?

Comment: Just different tools...I always use QueryOver (built on top of ICriteria) since it has the most NH features. Only reason I asked is in case someone is playing politics and only letting you use linq (IQueryable) interface.

Comment: This was a huge success! Still adding all the trimmings before I post the finished solution, but searching worked pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Mission accomplished! Created this in my base repository that all repositories inherit from, at the moment it's general enough to work across multiple entities, though I'm sure I'll encounter issues in the future. The only really funky thing here is that I expect children columns to be named as "parent.child", which is a convention I'm enforcing in DataTables column naming.

```
public ICriteriaWrapper GetWithPagingSortingFiltering(
    Type entityType,
    string columnNames, 
    List<bool> searchableColumns, 
    string searchParameter,
    int numSortingColumns,
    List<int> sortingColumns,
    List<string> sortingDirection, 
    int currentPage,
    int itemsPerPage)
{
    // Create the criteria for the given entity type
    var crit = _session.CreateCriteria(entityType);

    // Split the columns, which will be used as our properties
    var columns = columnNames.Split(',');

    // Add criteria for searchable columns, so long as a parameter is given
    if (searchParameter != string.Empty)
    {
        var disjunction = Restrictions.Disjunction();

        for (var i = 0; i < searchableColumns.Count; ++i)
        {
            if (searchableColumns[i])
            {
                var column = columns[i];
                var columnParts = column.Split('.');

                // Handles immediate children only
                if (columnParts.Count() == 2)
                {
                    var child = columnParts[0];
                    var aliasName = "the" + child;
                    var propertyName = aliasName + "." + columnParts[1];

                    crit.CreateAlias(child, aliasName);

                    disjunction.Add(
                        Restrictions.Like(
                            Projections.Cast(NHibernateUtil.AnsiString, Projections.Property(propertyName)),
                            searchParameter, MatchMode.Start));
                }
                // Handles base level properties
                else if (columnParts.Count() == 1)
                {
                    disjunction.Add(
                        Restrictions.Like(
                            Projections.Cast(NHibernateUtil.AnsiString, Projections.Property(column)),
                            searchParameter, MatchMode.Start));
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Unrecognized number of children; add more conditionals!");
                }
            }
        }

        crit.Add(disjunction);
    }

    // Grab the total items count
    var totalItemsCrit = CriteriaTransformer.Clone(crit);
    var totalItems = totalItemsCrit.SetProjection(Projections.RowCount()).UniqueResult();

    // Apply ordering
    for (var i = 0; i < numSortingColumns; ++i)
    {
        var direction = sortingDirection[i];
        var column = columns[sortingColumns[i]];

        if (direction == "asc")
            crit.AddOrder(Order.Asc(column));
        else if (direction == "desc")
            crit.AddOrder(Order.Desc(column));   
    }

    // Apply paging
    var startPage = (itemsPerPage == 0
                         ? 1
                         : currentPage/itemsPerPage + 1);

    crit.SetFirstResult(startPage).SetMaxResults(itemsPerPage);

    return new ICriteriaWrapper
        {
            Criteria = crit,
            TotalItems = Convert.ToInt32(totalItems)
        };
}
```